# What exactly happens (from a technical perspective) each time a PWA is opened up?

Tags: android, ios, google-chrome, progressive-web-apps

I've been trying to find some official documentation on this, but can't find anything really specific.

What exactly happens (from a technical perspective) each time a user opens up a PWA on Android? On iOS?

I'm asking because it seems the process is different when I haven't touched the PWA in a couple days vs. when I had the app open 20 minutes ago. How does Android (or iOS for that matter) decide when to refresh the page vs. display whatever was in memory (and/or whatever was cached by the service worker) from the last time the PWA was open? Does it do anything else I would want to know about, like automatically clear cookies/cache (after a certain period of time)? etc.

I feel like it's doing things I should know about, but can't find any official docs that are relevant. I understand the service worker life cycle (for the most part) but I feel like something else is going on.

Answer (score 0):

I have a general article on service workers and I dive into the service worker life cycle, which is a very deep topic.

https://love2dev.com/blog/what-is-a-service-worker/

If you open a PWA after 20 minutes of idle different browsers and operating systems handle this differently. For some the service worker may still be in some sort of alive, but sleeping state. Others it is completely dead.

No worries, it takes about 6ms for any of the browsers to wake it back up to respond to requests.

Now on iOS, Apple is very aggressive with purging unused cache after a few days. You have like 14 days before everything is wiped out so you start from scratch with caching. This is why you should always check the state of your cache when the service worker becomes active, etc.

So never assume your content is perfectly cached. If you know your application is used on a daily basis you might be able to relax a lot compared to a casual use application. For example a business app would be used 5 days a week (theoretical). So you can feel good iOS has not purged cache.

But even if assets are not cached and the user is connected to a network your application should still just work. Of course if you want that offline experience 30 days after last use you are sort of screwed on iOS :( Just one of Apple many short comings IMO.

Comment: I have a very weird behaviour on my pwa app, running on the iPhone. The app is reloading all resources if i close the app and re open it. By closing i mean removing it from the running apps.I have set up the browser cache, accordingly by adding the necessary http header on every response, to expire after a year. However its not respected. It seems like the cache is purged every time the app is closed.

Comment: the cache-control header is not in command of what gets cached by the service worker, your logic/code is. If you are not using the service worker to manage caching assets/data then you are at the mercy of the browser. Apple has always been hyper aggressive in purging items cached using legacy browser caching. They may ignore any caching all together if the response is larger than an allowed threshold.